# Fetch Logged In Username in a webapp secured with Keycloak

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, keycloak

I have secured an enterprise application with Keycloak using standard wildfly based Keycloak adapters. Issue that I am facing is that the rest web services when invoked, needs to know the username that is currently logged in. How do I get the logged in user information from Keycloak?

I tried using `SecurityContext` , `WebListener` etc. But none of them are able to give me the required details.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You get all user information from the security context.

Example:

```
public class Greeter {

  @Context
  SecurityContext sc;

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String sayHello() {

    // this will set the user id as userName
    String userName = sc.getUserPrincipal().getName();

    if (sc.getUserPrincipal() instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
      KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> kp = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>)  sc.getUserPrincipal();

      // this is how to get the real userName (or rather the login name)
      userName = kp.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdToken().getPreferredUsername();
    }

    return "{ message : \"Hello " + userName + "\" }";
}
```

For the security context to be propagated you have to have a security domain configured as described in the:
[JBoss/Wildfly Adapter configuration](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/ch08.html#jboss-adapter)

Comment: KeyCloakPrincipal is available from keycloak-core, for those who don't know where it is from

Comment: In case of Null Pointer Exceptions like I encountered when using the above with bearer token: Use `getToken()` instead of `getIdToken()`

Answer (score 20):

You may also set the `principal-attribute` property in the `keycloak.json` file of your web app to `preferred_username`.

Comment: Thank you! This is a much better answer than the accepted one because your answer allows a `SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal.getName` to work at the EJB layer if the entire project was packaged as an EAR.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add standalone.xml next line:

```
<principal-attribute>preferred_username</principal-attribute>
```

Example:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
    <secure-deployment name="war-name.war">
        <realm>realm-name</realm>
        <resource>resource-name</resource>
        <public-client>true</public-client>
        <auth-server-url>https://keycloak-hostname/auth</auth-server-url>
        <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
        <principal-attribute>preferred_username</principal-attribute>
    </secure-deployment>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Keycloak 3.4.3 (may also work on earlier versions) I was able to map username to the `sub` token claim name.  From the Keycloak admin interface this is done under `Clients > [your-client] > Mappers > username` and then enter `sub` in the `Token Claim Name` field.  This has the advantage of actually changing the contents of the `ID token` returned by Keycloak rather than adjusting client-side as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39225799/85464).  This is particularly nice when you're using a standard OpenID Connect library rather than an adapter provided by Keycloak.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was taking the preferred user name from the token like this

```
keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
token.getPreferredUsername();
```

To work i had to go to keycloak and add on my client template the add builtins if not added preferred username came null.

Check the username on the built ins, client template -> mappers.

After that if worked!