# Keycloak multi-tenancy and bearer-only microservice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, multi-tenant, keycloak

I have some Spring Boot microservices with Spring Cloud API gateway (Zuul) in front of them.
API gateway authenticates users and forward the Authorization bearer token header.
Working fine with a single realm.

Now, I'd like to use multiple realms.

Using [KeycloakConfigResolver](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_multi_tenancy), I'm able to authenticate user with the API gateway (keycloak deployment based on path).

But how should I configure KeycloakConfigResolver for microservices (bearer-only) so the use the right KeycloakDeployment? As every service can be accessed by both realms I don't know how to detect against which realm user was authenticated?

I cannot use path for `KeycloakConfigResolver` as for example for the order-service, users can do a GET on `/orders` being authenticated by realm1 or realm2...

Using header does not seem to be a good solution either....
Any idea?

I hope I'm clear enough...

Comment: `As every service can be accessed by both realms I don't know how to detect against which realm user was authenticated`. The realm entity is supposed to be opaque in keycloak. Doesn't this seem like a bit of hacking to you? Can't think of any benefit you get from using more than one realm here..

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `realm` from the `KeycloakPrincipal` (logged-in user) and then build `KeycloakDeployment` accordingly, you find the example [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/multi-tenant)

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/realm1-keycloak.json");
KeycloakDeployment deployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(is);
```

Comment: But as the user is only logged-in for the API Gateway client and not yet for the service behind API Gateway `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is null. The only info available for the service is the bearer token from header....

Comment: Check here on how to get KeycloakPrincipal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864062/fetch-logged-in-username-in-a-webapp-secured-with-keycloak

Comment: You need to have KeycloakConfigResolver in API gateway , so you can forward request to right realm