# Reading the user attributes from key cloak access token?

Tags: access-token, keycloak, userid

We have the access token from the Keycloak server and now we wanted to extract the user information from it .

Please guide me to get this done .

Comment: What platform is your application running on?

Comment: Here is the Solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864062/fetch-logged-in-username-in-a-webapp-secured-with-keycloak